# How to select collections that starts with a certain prefix using Firebase security rules wildcard

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have two sets of collections in firebase.
One set that starts with a prefix 'user'

For example

- /user_invoice
- /user_report

... etc

and the other set that does not start with any particular prefix.something like

- config
- customer

..etc

Is there a way that I can apply a set of security rules using wildcard or any other means for all the collections that starts with 'user_' and another set of rules for other set of collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select specific collections that starts with `user_` like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection=user_**}/{doc} {
      // Rules for collections that does start with user_
    }
    match /{collection=!(user_**)/{doc} {
      // Rules for collections that doesn't start with user_
      
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about control access to specific fields [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields).
I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot.  As of now I followed @frank-van-puffelen advice and did this match /{col}/{id} { allow read: if col.matches('user_.*');}

Comment: ok, I hope my answer helps you @AbhijitMazumder